# the_title - Filter strange behaviour: affects thumbnail

Tags: php, html, wordpress

we try to manipulate with `add_filter ('the_title', 'make_custom_title');` the title of WordPress posts. It works as far as we imagine. However, there is a strange side effect, the thumbnail is also influenced by it. Here is the source code and a screenshot:

```
function make_custom_title( $title) {
     $post_id = get_the_ID();
     $isAd = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mgofv_advertorial_isAd', true);
     if($isAd){
         return $title . '<br /><p style="font-size: 40%;">' . __( '[Advertorial]', 'mgofv-advertorial' ) . '</p> ';
     }
     else{
         return $title;
     }
}

function set_custom_title() {
   add_filter( 'the_title', 'make_custom_title');
}

add_action( 'loop_start', 'set_custom_title' );
```

Adding the filter to `loop_start` is important because of the Menu, that is otherwise changed.

In the screenshot you can see the correct "[Advertorial]" under the title, but the error occurs on the left... It looks like the "[Advertorial]" appears here several times in the html of the thumbnail.  We use the "Blog Designer" plugin to display the posts.

[Screenshot der Internetseite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX9nD.png)

If someone can tell us why this is the case and how to fix it, we are very grateful! We look forward to reading from you :)

Comment: I’m guessing that the post title is probably also used for the alt or title attribute of the post image here …?

Comment: yes that is quite possible ... it really looks like that! but how can we prevent that from being influenced?

Comment: I don’t think you can manipulate the title only for one context here, you will likely have to fix this at the other end then - where the post image itself is generated. `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` would be a promising hook to change the image attributes; not sure though whether you will be able to easily get the _original_ title back at this point though.